# Got Exception "Enumeration has either not started or has already finished" when try to get column from Dataset

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to filter dataset by using linq.It works fine

**Problem :**

But i try to get column from this it gives me that exception

**Enumeration has either not started or has already finished.**

here is my code :

```
foreach (string columnName in SelectedItems)
                {
                    var Rate = (from dr in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                where dr.Field<double>(columnName) > greater && dr.Field<double>(columnName) < less
                                select new
                                {
                                    rate = dr.Field<double>(columnName)

                                }.rate).ToList();
                    if (Rate.Count > 50)
                    {
                        var avg = Rate.CheckRateValue();

                    }


                    i++;
                }
```

i searched on web and find out the problem that dr.Field(columnName) must be use for single time.So how i can get column from linq query after skiping this code from Select new section.

Comment: Can you confirm exactly which line the error appears on...

Comment: When you step through this code, does it execute and you get the error after the foreach completes, or does it happen on a specific line within the code?

Comment: When i change query as 
 var Rate = (from dr in boundTable.AsEnumerable()
                                   select new
                                    {
                                        rate = dr.Field<double>(columnName)

then it works

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure *that* is your actual problem, but you can try:

```
var rates = (from dr in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
             let rate = dr.Field<double>(columnName)
             where rate > greater && rate < less
             select rate).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you sure your not getting the error from when itterating `SelectedItems` ?

Comment: When i change query as var Rate = (from dr in boundTable.AsEnumerable() select new { rate = dr.Field<double>(columnName) then it works

Comment: How about instead of `ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()` you do `ds.Tables[0]..AsEnumerable().ToList()` ?